# Spring batch - Commit failed while step execution data was already updated error

Tags: spring-batch, spring-boot

Im running a Spring Batch using Spring Boot, but im not sure if my springbatch config is missing something, or im starting incorrectly using springboot. (using springboot:1.0.2, spring-batch:2.2.6). I have a simple Batch configuration (reading from a H2 db and writing to file).

I have a couple of test records in the h2 db. When I start via gradlew bootRun, the first job execution fails with the following error. But subsequent jobs process correctly (for the same records). I tried various settings of delays and initial delays, they dont seem to affect the first execution. Is there any configuration I'm missing?

```
[pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils - TransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:101) ~[spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:106) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]


followed by

[pool-2-thread-1] INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
[pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing the step
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.getCurrentSession(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:51) ~[spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:85) ~[spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:928) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:740) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

My configurations are pretty straight-forward:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class MyJobScheduler {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher

    @Autowired
    Job myJob

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = '${jobDelay}', initialDelayString = '${initialDelay}')
    public void startJob() {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters()
        jobLauncher.run(myJob, jobParameters)

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        startJob()
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan
class MyBatchJobConfiguration {
  //ItemReader, ItemWriter, Job, Step etc. all implemented, works fine on 2+ runs
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] sources = [Application.class, MyJobsScheduler.class]
        SpringApplication.run(sources, args)
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

I'm using Gorm for data access. It is using Hibernate4 and the NPE comes from sessionHolder being null. It could be that somewhere in the configuration the sessionHolder is not initialized before the first query (because subsequent queries are fine). I will isolate this to a project and will update.

Per Dave's comment below, modified the build.gradle like this:

```
compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.3.RELEASE")
compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.0.0.RC3") {
    exclude module: 'spring-orm'
}
```

Complete Trace: Error: (happens only first time)

```
17:58:55.350 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils - TransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:107) ~[spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:106) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:941) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:783) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:117) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.commit(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:141) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:380) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:124) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:117) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher$run.call(Unknown Source) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at mypackage.MyJobScheduler.startJob(MyJobScheduler.groovy:38) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
17:58:55.351 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils - TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.afterCompletion(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:130) ~[spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:168) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:997) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:972) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:915) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:785) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:117) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.commit(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) [spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) [spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:141) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:380) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:124) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:117) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher$run.call(Unknown Source) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at mypackage.MyJobScheduler.startJob(MyJobScheduler.groovy:38) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
17:58:55.544 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
17:58:55.547 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step step1 in job pendingStatusReconcileJob
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.getCurrentSession(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:51) ~[spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:90) ~[spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:928) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:740) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:117) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.commit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:141) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:380) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:124) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:117) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher$run.call(Unknown Source) [spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120) [groovy-all-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at mypackage.MyJobScheduler.startJob(MyJobScheduler.groovy:38) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: We might need to see more of the stack trace. From a comment below it transpires that you are using GORM, so I suspect that's causing this issue somehow. If you can share a simple project that will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have an old (incompatible) version of Spring ORM on your classpath (spring-orm-3.2.8). Get rid of that and see if it works.

You might also want to add "spring.batch.job.enabled=false" to your external properties (since you are handling the job launching yourself, there's no need for Boot to do it).

Comment: Yes, spring.batch.job.enabled is already set to false. The orm:3.2.8 is picked up from org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.0.0.RC3 (org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.0.6.RELEASE). I excluded it from the dependency and explicitly added 

 compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.3.RELEASE")

Still the same issue. Updated original question with new exception above.